# Predictive dialing: Asterisk-Jitsi

Tags: asterisk

I wanted to develop a predictive dialing module for a project. I have a very crucial doubt, where should the actual predictive dialing process be running? Shouldn't it be running on the asterisk server? If so, could you please guide me towards documentation that would be helpful in my development process.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you not do that task, instead read code of opensource dialers.

If you still think you are enough of an expert in asterisk (but you are for sure not), you can start from this page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good dialers out - we use WombatDialer, but a lot of people are very happy with ViciDial or SineDialer. One of the reasons we started investigating WombatDialer was the reason why it was created - see http://www.wombatdialer.com/features.jsp - a dialer is not a simple piece of software, and you usually want the functionality, not handling all the details (and there are so many!)

Comment: I like ViciDial, or, rather it looks good, but for I like the idea of the dialer running distinctly from Asterisk itself.  Would you be able to expand your answer?

Comment: We investigated writing our own, but there are many things that you need to track, so it was a job better left for somebody else. Wombat is quite cheap and has worked well in the last couple of years. Initially it was lacking in the APIs but in the last year it has had a new configuration interface so that we can script it using curl in shell files. So we can create campaigns using scripts and deploy them to our multiple servers (we have approx 2,000 to 6,000 outgoing llines at any given moment).